# Is My Solution on Integration by Parts Correct?

Tags: integration

For $x>0$ let 
$\ f(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t-x^2⁄t} t^{-1/2}dt $

the question wants us to show that $\ f(x) = x \int_0^\infty e^{-t-x^2⁄t} t^{-3/2}dt $ by using substitution. However I do not think any substitution works here. What I have done so far is:

1. found $f'(x)$ as $\ f'(x) = -2x ∫_0^\infty e^{-t-x^2⁄t} t^{-3/2}dt $ and
2. using integration by parts i have,
        $\ f(x) = -2x^2 \int_0^\infty e^{-t-x^2⁄t} t^{-3/2}dt $

so that i get $\ f(x)= xf'(x) $ when i solve the differential equation i got $ f(x)= xe^C$ for some positive constant $C$ however the answer should be $ f(x)= Ce^{-2x} $ . I am totally wrong. Please help me. I can not go thorough..

Comment: There are many things that confuse me here. Firstly, neither $xe^C$ nor $Ce^{-2x}$ are solutions to the differential equation $f(x) = x' f(x)$. So I must be misinterpreting you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute this integral explicitly
$$
f(x)=\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=
\left\{s=\frac{x^2}{t}\right\}=
\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}e^{-\frac{x^2}{s}-s}\frac{xds}{\sqrt{s^3}}=
\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}}\frac{xdt}{\sqrt{t^3}}=
$$
Then
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}+\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}}\frac{xdt}{\sqrt{t^3}}\right)=
\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}+\frac{x}{2\sqrt{t^3}}\right)dt=
$$
$$
\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}e^{-\left(\sqrt{t}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^2-2x}d\left(\sqrt{t}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)=
\left\{u=\left(\sqrt{t}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\right\}=
\int\limits_{(-\infty,+\infty)}e^{-u^2-2x}du
$$
$$
e^{-2x}\int\limits_{(-\infty,+\infty)}e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2x}
$$
So,
$$
f'(x)=-2 f(x)
$$
P.S. Mathematica gives the same [results for $f(x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-t%20-%20x%5E2/t%5D/Sqrt%5Bt%5D,%20%7Bt,%200,%20%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D,%20%20%20Assumptions%20-%3E%20x%20%3E%200%5D)

Comment: The equation should be $f'(x) = -2 f(x)$

Comment: Yes you are right